# Do I need a transit visa to stay airside in Heathrow, as a Bangladeshi going to the British Virgin Islands

Tags: visas, transit, lhr, bangladeshi-citizens

I am a Bangladeshi student. I have got student visa from British Virgin Island immigration.

Do I need a transit visa to stay airside in Heathrow, as a Bangladeshi going to the British virgin Islands?